# MIPS in mars: address out of range

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to run a program but it gives me this errror "line 48: Runtime exception at 0x00400088: address out of range 0x00000000"

```
toUpperCase:
    bgt $t5, $s2, exit_toUpperCase  
    lb $t1, ($t5)           # address out of range in this line 
    add $t5, $t5, 1             
    bgt $t1, 96, check_ASCII_number     

    j toUpperCase
```

Comment: And which line is line 48?

Comment: could you please give us the whole code?Btw in order to load a byte using `lb` you must specify an address and my guess is that your `$t5` isn't and address thats why you are getting the issue.